# Probability that the first card drawn was a spade

Tags: probability

Suppose you draw $5$ cards out of a deck of $52$ and get $2$ spades and $3$ hearts. What is the probability that the first card drawn was a spade?

---

Is this question easier than it looks? Since we're only interested in the first card is it not simply $\frac{13}{52}$?

Comment: Do not forget that we have the additional phrase in the question **given that we got 2 spades and 3 hearts**.  Instead of thinking about drawing a card from a 52card deck, think about drawing it from a five card deck with two spades and 3 hearts comprising the entirety of the deck.  This is a question on [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability).

Comment: Oh! So the answer is $\frac{2}{5}$?

Comment: @JMoravitz One quick thing. Are you sure that's how it is? Isn't it asking what the probability that the first card of the 5 drawn cards was a spade? That's why I was thinking $\frac{13}{52}$. Wouldn't your approach give an answer of picking a spade from the actual 5 cards?

Comment: To aid with intuition, suppose it asked the probability that the first card chosen was a diamond.  that is clearly $0$, yes?

Comment: @lulu The first card from what exactly? From the original 52? Or from the 5?

Comment: It's your problem.  The first card you drew from the deck, conditioned on the fact that the eventual hand contains two spades and three hearts.

Comment: I think you are neglecting the information you have.  Sure, before you drew a card the probability that the first one was a spade was $\frac 14$.  But you have information and that changes things.  If I told you it was a black card, that would up the probability to $\frac 12$.  If I told you the first three cards were a spade, a diamond, and a club in some order, that would get you $\frac 13$.  And so on.

Comment: @lulu I guess I'm a little confused as to how the condition affects the probability of drawing a spade as the first card

Comment: So, go through my examples.  Suppose I assured you the first card was black.  Do you see that this makes the answer $\frac 12$?  Now suppose that your actual hand was $A\spadesuit, K\spadesuit, 2\heartsuit,3\heartsuit,4\heartsuit$ in some order,  What's the probability that the first card drawn was $2\heartsuit$?

Comment: Yes I see how the probability is $\frac{1}{2}$. And that would be zero since hearts are red but you assured me that the first card is black.

Comment: I was giving two different examples.  The second example is meant to line up with your problem.  In that example I say " you are told that the hand you draw is $A\spadesuit, K\spadesuit, 2\heartsuit,3\heartsuit,4\heartsuit$ in some order.  What is the probability that the first card you drew was $2\heartsuit$?"

Comment: Remember, we have to be assuming that every ordered hand is equiprobable.  That is, $A\spadesuit, K\spadesuit, 2\heartsuit,3\heartsuit,4\heartsuit$ is exactly as probable as $K\spadesuit, 2\heartsuit,A\spadesuit, 4\heartsuit,3\heartsuit$ or any other permutation.

Comment: Oh sorry about that. $\frac{1}{52}$?

Comment: No...the probability that the first card you drew was, say, $Q\clubsuit$ is $0$ right?  You know the card has to be one of the specified $5$.

Comment: Okay I see your point about the queen. Since we already know the cards drawn it was impossible for me to draw one of those.

Comment: I refer you again to the [article on conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability).  Continuing the conversation from your second comment, if you really insist on doing this the hard way, you could approach directly via the definition. Consider the sample space of all $5!\binom{52}{5}$ equally likely ways in which one could draw five cards from a well shuffled deck. Then consider the events where the five cards have specifically two spades and three hearts in any order vs where the first card is specifically a spade.  Calculate those sizes and apply definition

Comment: Since you know the card had to be one of  $A\spadesuit, K\spadesuit, 2\heartsuit,3\heartsuit,4\heartsuit$ and you know each order is equally probable, the probability that the $2\heartsuit$ was first is $\frac 15$.

Comment: The point however is that with practice, you could use your intuition and make easy shortcuts that simplify matters a great deal, e.g. how my first comment led you to the *correct* answer of $\frac{2}{5}$ with minimal calculation necessary.

Comment: I think I see now. I was thinking too hard. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 2):

This problem actually is easier than it looks. Probability is all about making the best prediction using all the information you have, so in this case, you should only focus on the five cards whose values you already know.

The probability that the first card drawn was a spade is the number of ways for a spade to come first divided by the total number of ways to draw those five cards in an ordered sequence.

---

The number of ways to draw a spade first is

> $$2\cdot{}_4P_4$$ You put the spade in first position, shuffle the other four around, add up the number of different permutations, and then repeat this for the other spade.

The number of ways to draw the five cards in an ordered sequence is

> $${}_5P_5$$ This is just your average permutation.

The final answer is

> $$\frac25$$